# What could be different in ApplicationPoolIdentity vs Normal User browser surfing?

Tags: iis, extjs, iis-7.5, extjs3, applicationpoolidentity

My web server runs an exe file (3rd party) that captures the screen of a web browser (using the emulator of IE7/IE9). The screen contains java script Extjs control that presents two columns. each column contains an image.

1) when my user runs the exe to this url I get they images in order (1 column, 2 column)
2) when the web server runs the exe (AplicationPoolIdentity) I get they images in bad order (2 column, 1 column)

What could be the difference between two users (My user vs ApplicationPoolIdentity) that can cause this behavior?

I run IIS7.5 
Windows 7 64bit
extjs 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user for the application pool was created when windows had localization setting set to a right to left language, that cause the java script control to change sides.

To remove the setting a had to manually delete the application pool user from c:\users directory and only then to recreate the application pool. (deleting the pool didn't help, user data stayed in c:\users)